# Has any jurisdiction mandated passenger training?

Tags: safety, passenger

A chunk of pre-departure time for each flight is dedicated to a safety briefing for passengers that few passengers seem to pay attention to. In the aftermath of accidents, it has been revealed at least a few times that passengers did not listen to or understand the briefing, or in the panic of the moment, forgot all about it.

A couple examples:

- [Southwest 1380: Air masks not properly worn](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/04/18/passengers-fail-to-wear-oxygen-masks-properly-aboard-southwest-flight.html)
- [BA 2276: Taking bags off during emergency evacuation](https://runwaygirlnetwork.com/2015/09/08/incidents-reveal-crucial-need-for-passengers-to-leave-bags-behind/)

With this in mind, has any civil aviation jurisdiction ever considered or implemented mandatory passenger training for commercial flights? (In the form of a short annual/bi-annual course requiring a passing grade in order to be allowed to fly. Sort of like CPR training, but for airline emergency procedures.)

Curriculum could include:

- Knowledge of oxygen mask usage
- Ability to exit plane properly during emergency (closest exit, no belongings)
- Emergency door operation
- Wayfinding in smoke-filled cabin

I'm not advocating for this, or suggesting it would be effective, but curious if it was ever considered, especially in the 50s or 60s when air travel was still relatively new (and somewhat more dangerous).

In the context of this question, I'm asking if a regulatory agency has attempted the above, *not* an airline or airport operator. Regulatory authorities are the one who require the current safety briefing approach.

Comment: What is the difference between the "passenger training" that you described, and the passenger briefings that already happen?

Comment: The crew is required by law to provide the passenger briefings today. Is your question whether anyone requires the passengers to actually pay attention? As a practical matter, I doubt that is possible...

Comment: Edited to be specific, let me know if not clear enough.

Comment: You can't force paying passengers to listen to or pay attention to anything the crew says. That is a conscious choice, and falls under the category of #YouCantFixStupid.

Comment: @JuanJimenez, yes for sure. And to reiterate, I'm not saying would be a) possible, b) a good idea or c) has ever happened. But I _can_ imagine a certain type of authority that _would_ think it's possible, and so am curious if that ever happened.

Comment: The offshore oil industry does require [helicopter survival training](https://mstc.louisiana.edu/courses/opito-certified-courses/t-huet-%E2%80%93-tropical-helicopter-underwater-escape-training) for its employees. You actually get dunked in a cabin simulator completely underwater with rollovers. These are commercial flights, though you're probably thinking of air carrier flights.

Comment: [some places offer course](https://nbaa.org/aircraft-operations/safety/flight-crews-training-your-passengers-for-emergencies/) for business passengers who regularly fly in smaller planes, i dont know of anywhere this is regulated.

Comment: @Dan1701 I would love to see airlines require passengers to view and complete a short online course on safety and passenger responsibilities.

Comment: @JuanJimenez I'm agnostic on whether it should be done or would be useful, but I was curious if it _had_ been done anywhere, so that the results could be examined. Mostly I find the pre-flight safety demo useless and was pondering if anything more effective might ever have been tried.

Comment: In Canada and the US many government workers flying small planes/ helicopters are mandated to take emergency underwater egress training, not sure if this counts as regulation, but it is a government requrement.